# How can I create Function Of driver.findelement( again function) In selenium

Tags: java, selenium, junit

```
    WebElement UserName = 
    driver.findElement(By.id(prop.getProperty("loginuser")));
    UserName.sendKeys(prop.getProperty("LoginUserName"));
    WebElement Password = 
    driver.findElement(By.id(prop.getProperty("loginpass")));
    Password.sendKeys(prop.getProperty("LoginPassword"));
    WebElement domain = 
    driver.findElement(By.id(prop.getProperty("logindomain")));
    Select selDomain = new Select(domain);
    selDomain.selectByVisibleText(prop.getProperty("LoginDomain"));
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnSignIn")).click();
```

I need to make a Function For the Driver.findelements(Which calls a function and automatically select the by.id or by.xpath or any method)

Comment: i have answered the question but try to search the internet before asking on stackoverflow. hope you mark my question

Comment: Your code trials for the wrapper around  `findelements()` please?

Answer (score 1):

```
/*this basic method will return driver.findElement. now its your job to tweak it from id to to any other element */

   public WebElement callElement(String id,String name){
       if (id.equals("id")) {
          return(driver.findElement(By.id(prop.getProperty(name))));
       }
       return null;
```

now instead of this:

```
WebElement UserName = driver.findElement(By.id(prop.getProperty("loginuser")));
```

you can can do something like:

```
WebElement UserName = callElement("id","loginuser");
```

Comment: Hi, I have used a function for taking the ID from properties file and then automatically selects which method needs to use i.e by.xpath, by.id, by.cssselecteor

Comment: if (locatorType.toLowerCase().equals("id"))
   return By.id(locatorValue);
  else if (locatorType.toLowerCase().equals("name"))
   return By.name(locatorValue);
  else if ((locatorType.toLowerCase().equals("classname")) || (locatorType.toLowerCase().equals("class")))
   return By.className(locatorValue);

Comment: i'm afraid if something what are saying is possible. since this is java most things are done manully. try to create a method with switch or elseif statment checking the parameter, and then decide which one to choose.

Comment: So I need to use your function calledElement(Getlocaor()) in a fashion of Function calling function type.

Comment: what you have posted up there should only work if you are dealing with a few element types. i don't think java have a builtin method to pick element automatically, so you'll have to check every possible case

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Login() throws Exception
{
    //WebElement UserName = driver.findElement(By.id(prop.getProperty("loginuser")));
    WebElement UserName = driver.findElement(map.getLocator("loginuser"));
    UserName.sendKeys(prop.getProperty("LoginUserName"));
    WebElement Password = driver.findElement(map.getLocator("loginpass"));
    Password.sendKeys(prop.getProperty("LoginPassword"));
```

I have use the method getlocator which automatically defines type of element xpath, id or css or any.

```
    public By getLocator(String ElementName) throws Exception {
        // Read value using the logical name as Key
        String locator = properties.getProperty(ElementName);
        // Split the value which contains locator type and locator value
        String locatorType = locator.split(":")[0];
        String locatorValue = locator.split(":")[1];

        System.out.println(locatorType);
        System.out.println(locatorValue);

        // Return a instance of By class based on type of locator
        if (locatorType.toLowerCase().equals("id"))
            return By.id(locatorValue);
        else if (locatorType.toLowerCase().equals("name"))
            return By.name(locatorValue);
        else if ((locatorType.toLowerCase().equals("classname")) || (locatorType.toLowerCase().equals("class")))
            return By.className(locatorValue);
        else if ((locatorType.toLowerCase().equals("tagname")) || (locatorType.toLowerCase().equals("tag")))
            return By.className(locatorValue);
        else if ((locatorType.toLowerCase().equals("linktext")) || (locatorType.toLowerCase().equals("link")))
            return By.linkText(locatorValue);
        else if (locatorType.toLowerCase().equals("partiallinktext"))
            return By.partialLinkText(locatorValue);
        else if ((locatorType.toLowerCase().equals("cssselector")) || (locatorType.toLowerCase().equals("css")))
            return By.cssSelector(locatorValue);
        else if (locatorType.toLowerCase().equals("xpath"))
            return By.xpath(locatorValue);
        else
            throw new Exception("Locator type '" + locatorType + "' not defined!!");
    }
```

So I need to mix the function which should call driver.findelement(Inside GetLocator()) to reduce the code.